# I wrote the function below and i need to capture the string value it generates and assign it to another variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

```
    var guess = 0;
    function search ()
    {
        var myWeapon ="";

        for (var i = 0; i <1; i++) {

            var myArray = ["rope","axe","crowbar","knife","shovel","hammer"];

            // random number generator
            guess = Math.floor(Math.random()* 6);

            // the generator generates just one random sting from six possible string, and passes it to myWeapon
            myWeapon = (myArray[guess]);

        }
    }

    search();
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: what should the function do?

Comment: i want to capture the string that the function generates

Comment: man edit the question, don't add a comment with the code inside!

Comment: that is what i want to fix, it should generate just one, After that i want it to capture the returned weapon and assign it to another variable outside the function

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you this solution :

```js
function generateWeapon() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  search();
}

function search() {
    var myArray = ["rope", "axe", "crowbar", "knife", "shovel", "hammer"];
    var guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    return myArray[guess];
}
```

```html
<button onClick="generateWeapon()">Generate a weapon</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: @andrew-bundo, consider flagging this answer as valid

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your function add `return myWeapon;` and you can later assign the result of the function call to a variable `weapon` by doing

```
var weapon = search();
```

You can also get rid of your loop because it loops only one time.

```js
function search() {
  var myArray = ["rope", "axe", "crowbar", "knife", "shovel", "hammer"];
  var guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  return myArray[guess];
}
var weapon = search();
alert(weapon);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>


var guess = 1;
var myWeapon = "";
function search() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var myArray = ["rope", "axe", "crowbar", "knife", "shovel", "hammer"];
        myWeapon = myArray[guess];
        // random number generator guess = Math.floor(Math.random()* 6);
        // the generator generates just one random sting from six possible string, and passes it to myWeapon myWeapon = (myArray[guess]);
    }
}

search();

    alert(myWeapon);

</script>
```

You have to add myWeapon outside of function to make it global.

Comment: i took myWeapon outside the function, it still wont work

Comment: It worked for me. I tested it in my system. And I am agree with the upvoted answer from halex.